# SwiftUI] access multiple NavigationStack

Tags: swiftui-tabview, swiftui-navigationstack

I use `TabView` & `NavigationStack`. `TabView` covered `NavigationStack` & inner `View` also covered `NavigationStack`. I want an inner navigation Push but it's always the root Navigation Push (in TabViewTest). Can I push the inner `NavigationStack` View (in PresentView)?

```
struct TabViewTest: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            TabView {
                PresentView()
                    .tabItem {
                        Image(systemName: "2.square.fill")
                    }
                Text("Another Tab")
                    .tabItem {
                        Image(systemName: "2.square.fill")
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}


struct PresentView: View {
    @State var stack = NavigationPath()
    @State var presentingModal = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $stack) {
            ZStack {
                Color.purple
                VStack {
                    NavigationLink(value: "hi") {
                        Image(systemName: "person")
                    }
                    .navigationDestination(for: String.self) { value in
                        PushedView(stack: $stack)
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct PushedView: View {
    @Binding var stack: NavigationPath
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.red
        
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(value: Color.red) {
                    Image(systemName: "person")
                }
                .navigationDestination(for: Color.self) { value in
                    Text("Hello")
                }
                
                
                Button {
                    stack.removeLast()
                } label: {
                    Text("pop")
                }

                
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There shouldn’t be a NavigationStack above the TabView it is against the human interface guidelines and causes many navigation bugs. Eac tab has to have its own

Comment: @loremipsum thanks  swiftui can't do that? tabBarController?.navigationController?.pushViewController() uikit is simple

Comment: What you are doing right now is “navigationController.tabControlller.navigationController.pushViewController” that isn’t allowed. Remove the outer one so you can resemble what you are describing.